# Convert access mid to sql substring

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have code I'd like to convert from access language to SQL.  I already converted the instr to charindex, just need to convert the mid piece.  The code basically takes a field that contains an email address that is always formatted john.doe@gmail.com and makes two columns one with the first name and one with the last name.  Here is the code:

```
SELECT sap.Description, Sum(main.Hours) AS SumOfHours, 
    substring(supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', supervisor1email) - 1) AS SupervisorFirstName, 
substring(supervisor1email, charindex('.', supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', supervisor1email) - charindex('.', supervisor1email) - 1) AS SupervisorLastName, 

(SELECT SUM(sub.hours) 

FROM v_MES_TcActivities sub

WHERE sub.costctr='106330' 
AND sub.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL'
AND sub.clockin Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))

AND substring(sub.supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', sub.supervisor1email) - 1) = substring(main.supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1) 

AND substring(sub.supervisor1email, charindex('.', sub.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', sub.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', sub.supervisor1email) - 1) = substring(main.supervisor1email, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', main.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1)

) AS TotalHours

FROM v_MES_TcActivities AS main
LEFT JOIN t_SAP_AttCodes AS sap 
ON main.AttCode = sap.Code

WHERE main.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL' 
AND main.CostCtr Like '106330' 
AND main.ClockIn Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))

GROUP BY sap.Description, substring(main.supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1), substring(main.supervisor1email, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', main.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1)

ORDER BY substring(main.supervisor1email, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', main.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1)
```

EDIT: Here is the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you specify the 3 arguments for `substring` (like you have already done for `MID`), you should be able to simply switch the function name itself and run the query.  Oh, and if this is SQL Server, `LEFT` will have to be converted to `substring` as well.

```
SELECT 
    sap.Description, Sum(main.Hours) AS SumOfHours,     
    substring(supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', supervisor1email) - 1) AS SupervisorFirstName,
    substring(supervisor1email, charindex('.', supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', supervisor1email) - charindex('.', supervisor1email) - 1) AS SupervisorLastName
```

**EDIT:** Here is a working mock-up, including dummy data

```
create table v_MES_TcActivities
(
supervisor1email varchar(100),
AttCode varchar(100),
Hours decimal(18,8),
costctr varchar(100),
clockin datetime default getdate()
);

create table t_SAP_AttCodes
(
Code varchar(100),
Description varchar(100)
);


insert into t_SAP_AttCodes (Code, Description) values ('NON-MEAL', 'not a meal');

insert into v_MES_TcActivities (supervisor1email, AttCode, costctr, Hours, clockin) values ('john.doe@gmail.com', 'NON-MEAL', '106330', 2, dateadd(hh, -2, getdate()));
```

And here is the exact query from above (formatted):

```
SELECT 
    sap.Description, Sum(main.Hours) AS SumOfHours, 
    substring(supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', supervisor1email) - 1) AS SupervisorFirstName, 
    substring(supervisor1email, charindex('.', supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', supervisor1email) - charindex('.', supervisor1email) - 1) AS SupervisorLastName, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(sub.hours) 
        FROM v_MES_TcActivities sub 
        WHERE sub.costctr='106330' AND sub.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL' 
        AND sub.clockin Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
        AND substring(sub.supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', sub.supervisor1email) - 1) = substring(main.supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1) 
        AND substring(sub.supervisor1email, charindex('.', sub.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', sub.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', sub.supervisor1email) - 1) = substring(main.supervisor1email, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', main.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1)
     ) AS TotalHours
FROM v_MES_TcActivities AS main
LEFT JOIN t_SAP_AttCodes AS sap 
ON main.AttCode = sap.Code
WHERE main.AttCode Not Like 'MEAL' 
AND main.CostCtr Like '106330' 
AND main.ClockIn Between dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) and dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
GROUP BY sap.Description, substring(main.supervisor1email, 1, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1), substring(main.supervisor1email, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', main.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1)
ORDER BY substring(main.supervisor1email, charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) + 1, charindex('@', main.supervisor1email) - charindex('.', main.supervisor1email) - 1)
```

And the results, showing the parsed first name / last name:

[image]

The query obviously parses the email correctly, so I think your original question about how to use `substring` is pretty well answered.  If you are still having problems getting your query to work, I suggest you look closely at the data in the tables to figure out if some values do not follow the "first.last@domain.name" pattern, or if you need other help with the sql, you should ask it as a separate question. Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function".  Any idea hat that may be?

Comment: is this SQL Server? If so, need to use substring everywhere (instead of LEFT, MID, RIGHT). I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  Should I increase that "1" value?

Comment: I had the args to substr in the wrong order - the edited version above is now corrected - sorry about that!

Comment: Why did you add the @ sign's?

Comment: because i was testing it :)  they're gone now - sorry again!

Comment: I'm still getting the same message.  I edited my post with the whole code.  Can you take a look?  It should have all of what you had exactly.